# Jenkins Job automation optimisation

Tags: jenkins

We have some scenarios to build automation for the same set of projects depends upon each other. we are creating the automation in Jenkins having overall 12 Jobs.Is there any way to create the 4 Jobs only rather 12?
which automatically can change the svn path and some global properties like the path to extract the jar and jar version.
path: This is the global variable which places the jar in this place once the jab 
                       is finished.
version: This is the global variable which instructs the Jenkins to create the
         jar of this version.

SVN location 1.

Project A
Project B
Project C
Project D

path 1 (global variable)
version 1(global variable)

SVN location 2.

Project A
Project B
Project C
Project D
path 2 (global variable)
version 2(global variable)

SVN location 3.

Project A
Project B
Project C
Project D

path 3 (global variable)
version 3(global variable)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer isn't very well formatted so it's a little hard to understand.. you may want to address that.

However I think you're basically asking is it possible to create one generic jenkins job rather than multiple jobs with hard-coded variables.

I'm not sure how you want to trigger the job, but you can use Build Parameters to set variables such as:

- **Parameter**: `VERSION`
- **URL inside the job**: `https://myurl.com/${VERSION}.jar`

If you need that to run on a schedule, there is a plugin that can run the same job on a cron schedule but with different parameters.

Alternatively, you can create multiple jobs with hard coded values that call the generic job. This doesn't really lessen the amount of jobs you have, but I suppose let's you split up the logic a bit - and stops you needing to install the plugin mentioned above (for allowing cron with parameters). This would look like:

- **Job A**: Runs on a cron (or with Build Now button) with hard-coded value such as VERSION=1, and calls generic job passing in that parameter.
- **Job B**: Runs on a cron (or with Build Now button) with hard-coded value such as VERSION=2, and calls generic job passing in that parameter.
- **Generic Job**: Like before, accepts a parameter of VERSION and has a URL inside the job like: `https://myurl.com/${VERSION}.jar`.